# If I copy a problem that contains only math terms out of book, is that violating copyright?

Tags: discussion, copyright

If I copy a purely mathematical problem from a book that is protected by copyright, am I doing any wrong? Because math can't be copyrighted, right?

Let me know if this should be in main...

Comment: When you make such post, you should certainly mention the book where the problem comes from.

Comment: Related: [Can someone copyright/own a math problem?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/6914/8348)

Comment: In terms of pure copyright: [facts cannot be copyrighted, but presentation of facts can be](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feist_v._Rural). Independently of copyright: copying things verbatim without attribution is _never_ a good thing.

Comment: That certainly depends on the domestic copyright law, which varies from country to country, and I think there can hardly be any definite conclusion before a case is tested in court.

Comment: This might not be related, but still a nice link: "Previously unknown mathematical formulas and laws of nature should also be patentable." From David Edwards's [Platonism Is the Law of the Land](http://www.ams.org/notices/201304/rnoti-p475.pdf)

Comment: If you copy a question verbatim, in quotation marks or some other way of showing that it is a quotation, for the purpose of academic discussion (and cite the source), I'm pretty sure this falls under "fair use". Moreover, there is much precedent for this kind of quotation: outside of math people quote from other sources in small chunks and inside math authors regularly state theorems from other papers. Given that math questions have such a limited vocabularly, small quotations seem inevitable, so I wouldn't worry.